# OSGI JPA Persistence - Handling multiple model bundles persistence.xml

Tags: jpa, osgi, persistence, apache-karaf, persistence.xml

In my project i have a persistence bundle which will perform the create/update/delete operations and multiple model bundles.

### persistence bundle:

1. PersistenceService.java - Exposed as a service.
2. PersistenceServiceImpl.java
3. persistence.xml - contains:
     a: jta-data-source details
     b: dialect properties.

Now i have multiple model bundles where i have used annotations for declaring entities.

My query is, how i can specify the different model bundles details in the above mentioned persistence bundle's persistence.xml. so that the i can maintain a single persistence.xml file and "PersistenceUnitInfo" will not be repeated.

is it possible? or is there any other best practices?

Comment: I think this is not possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983361/osgi-using-jpa-persistence-unit-from-another-bundle.

Comment: All entities should be in the same bundle, but you can have multiple persistence.xml using the same entities.